# Vb.net Change single line font and color of text in textbox

Tags: vb.net, textbox

I am making a function which can check strength of password. I have a problem to change single line text font and color. I know that I change text color and font for whole textbox, but is that an option to change only text font and color for single line of text in textbox?

Code:

```
  Function Checker(password)
              

    Dim i, l, c, k As Byte
    Dim array() As Char = password.ToCharArray()

    For i = 0 To array.Length - 1
        If Char.IsUpper(array(i)) Then
            c += 1
        ElseIf Char.IsLower(array(i)) Then
            l += 1
        ElseIf Char.IsNumber(array(i)) Then
            k += 1
        ElseIf Char.IsSymbol(array(i)) Then
            i += 1
        End If
    Next

    If i >= 2 And k >= 3 And 2 >= 1 And c >= 2 And password.Length >= 6 Then
        pnlCheckPass.txtChcekPass.Font = New Font("Microsoft YaHei UI", 10)
        pnlCheckPass.txtChcekPass.ForeColor = Color.DarkGreen
        pnlCheckPass.txtChcekPass.Text = " - Very strong password"
    ElseIf k >= 3 And l >= 2 And c >= 2 And i >= 2 And password.Length >= 6 Then
        pnlCheckPass.txtChcekPass.ForeColor = Color.Green
        pnlCheckPass.txtChcekPass.Font = New Font("Microsoft YaHei UI", 10)
        pnlCheckPass.txtChcekPass.Text = " - Strong password"
    ElseIf k >= 2 And i >= 1 And c >= 1 And password.Length >= 6 Then
        pnlCheckPass.txtChcekPass.Font = New Font("Microsoft YaHei UI", 10)
        pnlCheckPass.txtChcekPass.ForeColor = Color.Orange
        pnlCheckPass.txtChcekPass.Text = " - Medium password"
    ElseIf k = 1 And i >= 1 And password.Length = 4 Then
        pnlCheckPass.txtChcekPass.BackColor = Color.Red
        pnlCheckPass.txtChcekPass.Font = New Font("Microsoft YaHei UI", 10)
        pnlCheckPass.txtChcekPass.Text = " - Weak password"
    ElseIf k = 1 Then
        pnlCheckPass.txtChcekPass.ForeColor = Color.DarkRed
        pnlCheckPass.txtChcekPass.Font = New Font("Microsoft YaHei UI", 10)
        pnlCheckPass.txtChcekPass.Text = " - Very weak password"
    Else
        pnlCheckPass.txtChcekPass.ForeColor = Color.IndianRed
        pnlCheckPass.txtChcekPass.Font = New Font("Microsoft YaHei UI", 10)
        pnlCheckPass.txtChcekPass.Text = " - Blank password"
    End If

    Return pnlCheckPass.txtChcekPass.Text
End Function
```

(Explanations:)
pnlCheckPass - is form where i have a textbox

Comment: Use a RichTextBox instead.

Comment: You cannot do this in a TextBox, you will need to take @Jimi's advice and use a RichTextBox instead. Is this acceptable? If so, I can provide you with an example.

Comment: Will you please show me an example? Thank you